# How to create multiple png files using styler function

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-styles

Below is the example script/data I am working with. When trying to create multiple png files using a list, `test = []`, running this script gives me this error `OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'test<pandas.io.formats.style.Styler object at 0x0000025FD890D250>.png'`. I think the error is coming from the last loop,`dfi.export(df, f'test{i}.png')` any suggestions to output all the data frames in the list would be great.

```
import pandas as pd
import dataframe_image as dfi

df = pd.DataFrame(data=[[-100,500,400,0,222,222], [9000,124,0,-147,54,-56],[77,0,110,211,0,222], [111,11,-600,33,0,22],[213,-124,0,-147,54,-56]])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data=[[100,500,200,0,555,222], [5000,124,0,-147,54,50],[77,0,500,211,0,222], [-900,11,-600,33,0,22],[500,-124,0,-147,54,-56]])

df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['x','y','z'], list('ab')])
df2.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['x','y','z'], list('ab')])

df_list=[df,df2]

def colors(i):
    if i > 0:
        return 'background: red'
    elif i < 0:
        return 'background: green'
    elif i == 0:
        return 'background: yellow'
    else:
        ''

test=[]
for df in df_list:
    filename=(df.style
        .applymap(colors, subset=pd.IndexSlice[:, pd.IndexSlice[:,'a']])
    )
    test.append (filename)
    
    for df in test:
        dfi.export(df, f'test{i}.png')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If need numeric suffix in new filenames of `png` like `test0` and `test1` here use:

```
for i, df in enumerate(test):
    dfi.export(df, f'test{i}.png')
```

Another solution without another loop:

```
for i, df in enumerate(df_list):
    styler=(df.style
              .applymap(colors, subset=pd.IndexSlice[:, pd.IndexSlice[:,'a']])
    )
    dfi.export(styler, f'test{i}.png')
```

Comment: Thanks so much, jezrael. What does 'IIUC' stand for? In terms of performance, what would be better? Maybe the second option since there is no need for an additional loop?

Comment: @yeppi - it mens if understand well your question. Btw, you are right, second is better, because no another loop.